# My code in Brackets is not reading the files I call

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I have a bunch of folders on my desktop (working on a Mac) and I am trying to call various files into my style.css file and index.html files. Rather than trying to post a complicated explanation of all my directories/code, could someone please explain to me how calling files into my code works? How do file tree hiearchies work in [adobe-brackets](/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets)? For example, if I have three folders:

- Parent Folder/ Folder A / Code/ index.html
- Parent Folder / Folder A / Images/ cat.jpg
- Parent Folder/ Folder B / MoreImages / dog.jpg
- Parent Folder / Folder C / MoreCode / style.css

If my index file is in Folder A, and I want to call the cat image, do I write Folder A/ Images/ cat.jpg or do I only need to write Images / cat.jpg ?

And to call items outside of Folder A, so in Folders B and C, do I need to do anything in [adobe-brackets](/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets) in order for [adobe-brackets](/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets) to understand where these folders are located? As an example, I was trying to call my style.css sheet into my index.html file. I did so by simply writing Folder C/ MoreCode/ style.css. I also double clicked my style.css sheet to add it to my working file list in Brackets. However, my style sheet still was not being read by my html file.

Comment: You're capitalizing "Brackets" which sort of implies it's a proper name, like the [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) editor — or do you mean "angle brackets" like Deep Patel seems to assume in their answer?

Comment: @StephenP I am in fact referring to the Brackets editor.

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure works from the file(s) current location. For instance, if your `index.html` file is in the following location:

```
Parent Folder/Folder A/Code/index.html
```

And you want to call the cat image, you would use the following path:

```
../Images/cat.jpg
```

`../` - Move out of the current directory (Code), back to the previous
directory (Folder A).

`Images/` - Look for a directory called Images.

`cat.jpg` - Display the cat.jpg image.

Likewise, to load your stylesheet, you would need to move back two directories. Out of the current directory `Code/`, then out of the `Folder A/` directory, back to the `Parent Folder/` directory. So you would use:

```
../../Folder C/MoreCode/style.css
```

I would also remove the whitespace from your directory names as this can cause issues, so instead of `Parent Folder/Folder A/`, change it to `ParentFolder/FolderA/`.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="picture.jpg">`   picture.jpg is located in the same folder as the current page

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg">

picture.jpg is located in the images folder in the current folder

<img src="/images/picture.jpg">

picture.jpg is located in the images folder at the root of the current web

<img src="../picture.jpg">

picture.jpg is located in the folder one level up from the current folder
```

To call your styles sheet since it is 2 levels down add the period period three times and then / then name of folder and your style sheet name.

Straight from W3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp